# Sharing Material Libraries

Tags: materials

I have built up my own procedural Material Library and having just bought a new PC, I want to copy and it to the new computer? Can this be done as simply as using a USB drive?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Simply copy the directory containing the library onto the USB drive.  On the new PC create a folder hierarchy just like the one on the old pc, ie, I have `D:\\blender\\materials` as my directory, so I would go to my home directory on the new PC and create a `blender` folder.  Then just copy the folder from the USB drive to the blender folder (or your equivalent) on your new PC.

Comment: Thank you for that. I can't find such a directory anywhere on my system. I've checked everywhere including program files but no joy. However, I did find that by copying a blend file that uses the library I can now open the library on my new PC. Thanks again for your response.